# LineString VS Multi-LineString Performance PostGIS

Tags: postgis, performance, linestring

Our road dataset (14mil segments, 300,000+ km length) is in Multi-LineString, I am thinking about shifting it all to LineString since all the roads in our data are single geometries and multi part geometries are errors. LineString also provides several different functions that I am really fond of using like [ST_StartPoint](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_StartPoint.html) and [ST_EndPoint](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_EndPoint.html).

Is there any difference in the performance of **LineString** and **Multi-LineString**? and what is the recommended format for storing a large road dataset in PostGIS?

***In response to the Comments:***
It's not a single Multi-LineString, each one is a different feature. Number of geometries in each feature is 1.
I am not looking for the performance of a specific query.

*What I want to know is the difference in speed of full table scans for LineString, and for the same geometry, stored as MultiLineString. Does the geometry type have any impact? The results of explain and the queries I tried, kept on fluctuating and there wasn't any noticeable difference*

Comment: Is it one huge MLS or many MLS?

Comment: more than 14mil MLS, each one is a different feature, Number of geometries for each feature is 1.

Comment: what kind of performance you are talking about? Is it on indexing, or fetching records or performance of applying spatial operations.

Comment: Overall performance, on spatial and non spatial functions both

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.  Full table scans on large tables are **never** fast, and cannot be so. You need to provide a ***specific*** query and the `EXPLAIN` plan before we could help.

Comment: I am not looking for the performance of a specific query. What I want to know is if there is any difference in the performance based on the type of geometry, specifically LineString and Multi-LineString.

Comment: Have you tried reloading as LineString and evaluated performance without any  metrics or basis? How did that work for you?

Comment: What I want to know is the difference in speed of full table scans for LineString, and for the same geometry, stored as MultiLineString. Does the geometry type have any impact? The results of explain and the queries I tried, kept on fluctuating and there wasnt any noticeable difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't expect any significant difference in performance unless you have very unusual data.  There are a few places in the code where optimizations are put in for edge cases like two-point LineStrings, and you will miss out on some of these if you're storing your LineStrings as MultiLineStrings.  There may be some special code paths in GEOS that you miss out on with MultiLineStrings as well.

There's a storage overhead to Multi* geometries, which will be small as long as the number of points in your geometry is small (really, it's only significant for single-point MultiPoints).

That said, if your geometries all have only a single component, there is no advantage to storing them as MultiLineStrings, so you may as well convert to LineString.  If nothing else, this will make your data model more self-documenting.

Comment: Thats what I thought as well, what is the recommended format for storing road data?

Comment: It depends on the type of queries. Please try to follow Vince's comments...